# Convert Angular Web Application to android application through cordova. If not cordova any other framework suggestions

Tags: angular, cordova, angular5

I have created a web application in Angular. Now I want to make that application into an android application. How can I achieve it through cordova? If not cordova then any other suggestions to converted angular web app to android app.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Ionic Framework its built with angular 4,5 you can reuse the same code and there are some changes .. first you have to create new ionic app and reuse the components and services in IONIC for more documentation you can refer this link   [here](https://ionicframework.com/)

Comment: Ok Thank You I will go through the documentation once.

Comment: Best of luck ... :)